# How to apply color variable to linear-gradient with opacity

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I need to apply color variable to `liner-gradient`, which also needs to have `opacity`. So in that case `rgba(red, green, blue, opacity)` is mandatory. **Is there any way to apply variable color without hard coding `rgba()` in liner-gradient?**

For instance :

```
 let gradient= `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 20%)`

.arraow {
   background: ${(p) => p.gradient}
 }
```

The above code is only for one color and taht is `#FFFFFF` at the moment. But this needs to change depending on color selected for the gradient to use.

**I need** something like below:

```
const gradientColor = p.arrowColor;

let gradient= `linear-gradient(to bottom, var(gradientColor) 15%, var(gradientColor) 40%, 
var(gradientColor) 20%)` <<<<<------ here I am missing the opacity since they are not rgba()
```

It doesn't seem a nice way to manually create all `rgba()` and keep it a file and access it with a `conditional` statement.

Comment: You create 5 variables....one each for R G B A and a combined variable with all of them included.

Comment: Could you please show some example?Also how would I know the RGB values for applied colors? For instance for `#FFFFFF` `rgba(255, 255, 255)`, if `#3D3DA0` then it would be `rgba(61, 61, 160). I am only getting `hex code` for colors in my app. Does it require to generate `rgba` for it?

Comment: But you are using RGBA not hex right?

Comment: I used `rgba()` and hardcoded them to work initially. Now I need variable so I can't hard code colors. I need to use colors that are selected by the user and that is `hex code`. I need to use `hex code` with three different opacity in three different position which is used as `%`.